# Selenium Golang binding without server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, go

There are many selenium webdriver binding package of Golang.
However, I don't want to control browser throught server.

How can I control browser with Golang and selenium without selenium server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [github.com/fedesog/webdriver](https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver) which says in its documentation:

> This is a pure go library and doesn't require a running Selenium driver.

Answer (score 0):

I would characterize the Selenium webdriver as a client rather than a server. Caveat: I have used the Selenium webdriver (Chrome version) from .Net and I am assuming it is similar for Go.

The way Selenium works is that you will launch an instance of it from within code, and it creates a live version of the selected browser (i.e. Chrome) and your program retains control over it. Then you write code to tell the browser to navigate to a page, inspect the response, and interact with the browser by filling out form data, clicking on buttons, etc. You can see what is happening on the browser as the code runs, so it is easy to troubleshoot when the interaction doesn't go as planned.

I have used Selenium to upload tens of thousands of records to a website that has no API and only a graphical user interface. Give it a chance.